# Is it valid to have default template arguments that are dependent on earlier arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters

For example, the following snippet compiles in VC++ 2010:

```
template<int Rows, int Columns = Rows>
struct Matrix {  };

Matrix<4> m;
```

Note that the default argument for `Columns` depends on the argument value for `Rows`.

But is this *standard* behaviour in C++11 (or earlier) that I can rely on everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. And as a matter of fact, it's how tons of STL codes work.

the `std::vector` has a definition like:

```
 template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector
```

so that you don't need to specify the `allocator` each time every time. If such is invalid, we won't be able to write:

```
std::vector<int> data;
```

And you would write `std::map` as:

```
std::map < keyType,                                     // map::key_type
       ValType,                                       // map::mapped_type
       less<keyType>,                     // map::key_compare
       allocator<pair<const KeyType,ValType> >    // map::allocator_type
       > mapping;
```

which is far less desirable than:

```
std::map< keyType , ValType > mapping;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/), yes:

It is also possible to set default values or types for class template parameters. For example, if the previous class template definition had been:

```
template <class T=char, int N=10> class mysequence {..};
```

And on a more mundane note, g++ -Wall will compile it.